# inconsistent accessibility:constrain type "special" is less accessible than item database generic save objects

Tags: c#

i have an interface like this.

```
interface special
{
     int spz_ID { get; set; }

     string Specialization_name { get; set; }

}
```

And I have a generic method expects T types that implemented interface.

```
public int SaveObjects<T>(T obj) where T : special
    {

        lock (locker)
        {
            if (obj.spz_ID != 0)
            {
                database.Update(obj);
                return obj.spz_ID;

            }
            else
            {
                return database.Insert(obj);
            }


        }
    }
```

and other table has different interface like this

```
public  interface IObject
{
    int ID { get; set; }

    string Username { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }



}
```

generic method for this table is  expects T types that implemented interface is

```
 public int SaveObject<T>(T obj) where T : IObject
    {

        lock (locker)
        {
            if (obj.ID != 0)
            {
                database.Update(obj);
                return obj.ID;

            }
            else
            {
                return database.Insert(obj);
            }


        }
    }
```

When I build my solution i have an error :
inconsistent accessibility:constrain type "special" is less accessible than item database generic save objects (T).

Comment: Change ` interface special` to `public  interface special`

Answer (score 1):

You method is defined as `public`. That requires the generic type `T` also to be public. As it has a constraint of being of type `special` that type must also be public.

Interfaces by default are created as `internal` if not explicitly stated otherwise thus are less accessible than `public`.

Change your interface definition to `public` and you are fine:

```
public interface special 
{
    //... member definitions
}
```

If you do not want your interface to be `public` any method using that interface mustn't be either.